# CKeditor instanceReady is not working in version 4.18.0

Tags: ckeditor4.x

I have to make sure instance is ready or not before setting data.
So, I have added instanceReady as below

```
 var editor = CKEDITOR.instances\['instanceName'\];
 editor.on('instanceReady',function(e){
e.setData("test Data");
});
```

Tried with ready as well, But It did not work as expected. So, forced to keep timer to update the data in CKEDITOR on load.